# PHP mail From problem

Tags: php, email, header

```
$full_name = $stu_first . ' ' . $stu_mid . ' ' . $stu_last;
header( "Location: http://www.wvys.org/redirect2.php" );
mail( "albertnov29@gmail.com", "Registration Details", $full_name ,$fullname );
header( "Location: http://www.wvys.org/redirect2.php" );
```

Whenever I try this, I get unknown sender on my gmail account.  Help would be appreciated :D

Comment: It would help tremendously to know the contents of `$fullname`...

Answer (score 0):

```
mail( "username@gmail.com", "Registration Details", $content , "From: Name Of Sender <address@example.com>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `"From: Full Name <email@address>"` header. See http://php.net/mail!

Comment: I just tried that.  Still nothing.  I put in "From: $full_name"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing almost every important header in your email. Set at least the "From" and "Reply-To" headers - [**mail()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).